# Position: absolute causing my Carousel to glitch

Tags: mobile, carousel, css-position

None of the carousel plugins I use are working properly. Usually I need to resize my browser before everything is displayed properly. This is not practical because mine is a mobile app.

I have nailed down the problem to positioning. The transition between pages requires the positioning to be Absolute (see `#page > div`). However, the carousel requires the Relative positioning.

I tried adding an extra `<div></div>` around the carousel and positioning that to be relative, but it isn't doing the trick. Anyone know how to fix this...

Transition.css:

```
#page {
  position: relative;
}

#page > div {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#page > div.current {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/transition.css?v=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elastislide.css?v=1">
</head>

<body>
<div id="page">  

<div id="pageLogin" class="pageLogin current">
    <a href="#pageSearch" id="signIn" class="button small brown"><span>Sign in</span></a>
</div>


<div id="pageSearch" class="pageSearch">
    <!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
    <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="es-carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/5.jpg" alt="image05" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Elastislide Carousel -->
</div> <!--! end #pageSearch-->
</div><!--end #Page-->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem. Its actually the `display:none` and `display:block`, that was applied to the pages.

The display block caused the carousel's images to display block style instead of side by side.

Instead of `display:none`, I use `visibility:hidden`, `height: 0`, `overflow: hidden`. Then I just reverse it when the page displays.

Answer (score 0):

I also had and solved this problem.

I used some jQuery to apply the css once the document was loaded.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.more-wrapper').css({"display": "block", "position": "absolute", "left": "50%", "z-index": "100", "bottom": "40px", "-webkit-transform": "translate(-50%,0)", "-ms-transform": "translate(-50%,0)", "-o-transform": "translate(-50%,0)", "transform": "translate(-50%,0)"});
});
```